# Struct pointer ? Something goes wrong

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hi I am trying to make a program with pointer in a struct. Compiler appears no problems but the program crashes.
Could you help me please ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int pos;

typedef struct _Parking Parking;

struct _Parking
{
    int   pos;    
    char  name[15];       
    char  description[80];  
    float price;         
    int   slots[5];       
    char  last_driver_id;    
    int   reservations;   
};

Parking *myaccounts;

int create_Parking()
{
    strcpy(myaccounts->name,"Pro");
    myaccounts->pos ++;

    return pos-1;               
}

int main()
{

    int a;

    a = create_Parking();

    printf("a=%d\n",a);
    printf("name=%s\n",myaccounts->name);

    system("pause");    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: @user494766: if you were please by one o more of the answers (and you should), you should "accept" the one that you feel best.

Answer (score 8):

Your myaccounts pointer is initialized to NULL (as a global variable) and does therefore not point to usable memory. Try the manual page for malloc for more information.

Edit: Incorporated Maciej's comment.

Comment: Looks like `myaccounts` is a global. Globals get zero-initialized, don't they?

Comment: @Maciej: You are right. I will update the wording of the answer.

Comment: A zero-initialized pointer is not a valid pointer.  Plus, zero-initialized or not, I wouldn't recommend using a variable that's not been explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 6):

You never allocate any memory for "myaccounts".

Answer (score 3):

Pointers in C do not point to valid memory (and will crash if you try to use them), until you specifically point them somewhere valid by using the address-of operator on an object (`&`) or by allocating memory for them and assigning that address into the pointer (`malloc()` and friends). Of course if you use the address-of operator that location can go invalid when the object goes out of scope. If you use `malloc()` that location can go invalid when `free()` is called. In either case, your pointer will become invalid again.

C is hugely reliant on pointers too, so you can count on any C code you write of any size having a bug or two of this nature until you track them down and fix them. Getting your sources past the compiler in C really doesn't mean much. If you want to write in a language where your code is liable to work first time you run it after getting it past the compiler, you want Ada.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer doesn't point to anything.  You can try either one of these:

```
Parking myaccountsInstance;
Parking *myaccounts = &myaccountsInstance;
```

Or in the main function:

Start with:

```
myaccounts = (Parking*)malloc(sizeof(Parking));
```

And end with:

```
free(myaccounts);
```

Comment: Please do not teach people to ignore the error condition for `malloc`.

Comment: The cast of the return value of `malloc` is actually harmful. See http://www.cpax.org.uk/prg/writings/casting.php for more information about why.

Comment: Personally Helmut, I wouldn't teach people to use global variables, but I was trying to teach, I was trying to address the question.

Comment: Too used to C++, and in C++ you definitely have to cast it, but, yes in C you shouldn't because it will mask a problem if you don't prototype the malloc function call first.